# FileNotFoundError: [Errno2] No such file or directory: 'i'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am using TensorFlow 2.2.0 (Python 3.8.3, in Anaconda3) and have finished training a model for object detection. I am running a script named "detect_objects.py" which can be seen in the script directly below. I have specified an image path to 10 test images to test how well the model was trained.

```
#Import modules
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging (1)

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')   # Suppress Matplotlib warnings

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')           # Suppress TensorFlow logging (2)

# Enable GPU dynamic memory allocation
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)


#Specify directory where trained model is saved
PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL = 'exported-models\my_model\saved_model'

print('Loading model...', end='')
start_time = time.time()

# Load saved model and build the detection function
detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load(PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL)

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print('Done! Took {} seconds'.format(elapsed_time))

#Path to .pbtxt file
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap('annotations\label_map.pbtxt',use_display_name=True)


#Detect objects in images
def load_image_into_numpy_array(path):
    """Load an image from file into a numpy array.

    Puts image into numpy array to feed into tensorflow graph.
    Note that by convention we put it into a numpy array with shape
    (height, width, channels), where channels=3 for RGB.

    Args:
      path: the file path to the image

    Returns:
      uint8 numpy array with shape (img_height, img_width, 3)
    """
    return np.array(Image.open(path))

#Specify path for test images
IMAGE_PATHS = 'images\evaluation_images'

for image_path in IMAGE_PATHS:

    print('Running inference for {}... '.format(image_path), end='')

    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)

    # Things to try:
    # Flip horizontally
    # image_np = np.fliplr(image_np).copy()

    # Convert image to grayscale
    # image_np = np.tile(
    #     np.mean(image_np, 2, keepdims=True), (1, 1, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

    # The input needs to be a tensor, convert it using `tf.convert_to_tensor`.
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
    # The model expects a batch of images, so add an axis with `tf.newaxis`.
    input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]

    # input_tensor = np.expand_dims(image_np, 0)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    # All outputs are batches tensors.
    # Convert to numpy arrays, and take index [0] to remove the batch dimension.
    # We're only interested in the first num_detections.
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                   for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'],
          detections['detection_classes'],
          detections['detection_scores'],
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.30,
          agnostic_mode=False)

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
    print('Done')
plt.show()

# sphinx_gallery_thumbnail_number = 2
```

The following error is produced:

```
Loading model...Done! Took 35.13338613510132 seconds
Running inference for i... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_objects.py", line 64, in <module>
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
  File "detect_objects.py", line 55, in load_image_into_numpy_array
    return np.array(Image.open(path))
  File "C:\Users\user\pillow-8.0.1-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\PIL\Image.py", line 2891, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'i'
```

What is causing this error? Do I have a bug in my code?

For reference, here is the line 2841 through 2898 in `Image.py` script that is being referenced in the error:

```
def open(fp, mode="r", formats=None):
    """
    Opens and identifies the given image file.

    This is a lazy operation; this function identifies the file, but
    the file remains open and the actual image data is not read from
    the file until you try to process the data (or call the
    :py:meth:`~PIL.Image.Image.load` method).  See
    :py:func:`~PIL.Image.new`. See :ref:`file-handling`.

    :param fp: A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or a file object.
       The file object must implement ``file.read``,
       ``file.seek``, and ``file.tell`` methods,
       and be opened in binary mode.
    :param mode: The mode.  If given, this argument must be "r".
    :param formats: A list or tuple of formats to attempt to load the file in.
       This can be used to restrict the set of formats checked.
       Pass ``None`` to try all supported formats. You can print the set of
       available formats by running ``python -m PIL`` or using
       the :py:func:`PIL.features.pilinfo` function.
    :returns: An :py:class:`~PIL.Image.Image` object.
    :exception FileNotFoundError: If the file cannot be found.
    :exception PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: If the image cannot be opened and
       identified.
    :exception ValueError: If the ``mode`` is not "r", or if a ``StringIO``
       instance is used for ``fp``.
    :exception TypeError: If ``formats`` is not ``None``, a list or a tuple.
    """

    if mode != "r":
        raise ValueError(f"bad mode {repr(mode)}")
    elif isinstance(fp, io.StringIO):
        raise ValueError(
            "StringIO cannot be used to open an image. "
            "Binary data must be used instead."
        )

    if formats is None:
        formats = ID
    elif not isinstance(formats, (list, tuple)):
        raise TypeError("formats must be a list or tuple")

    exclusive_fp = False
    filename = ""
    if isinstance(fp, Path):
        filename = str(fp.resolve())
    elif isPath(fp):
        filename = fp

    if filename:
        fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
        exclusive_fp = True

    try:
        fp.seek(0)
    except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
        fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
        exclusive_fp = True
```

Comment: `IMAGE_PATHS` is a string. Iterating over a string with "for" means iterating over each character separately.

Comment: @MichaelButscher It should be specifying a directory. I'm working from the Anaconda prompt with a "cd" command set to the parent folder of "images." Is there another way to indicate a file path?

Comment: You can make `IMAGE_PATHS` a list with only one item (the path string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @MichaelButscher mentioned `IMAGE_PATHS = 'images\evaluation_images'` is a string. if your images are in the same folder as your code, change this line to

```
import os
directory,filename = os.path.split( __file__ )
IMAGE_PATHS = [directory + "\\" + f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f[-4:] in ['.jpg','.png','.bmp']]
```

otherwise change it to

```
import os
directory = "give path to your image folder"
IMAGE_PATHS = [directory + "\\" + f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f[-4:] in ['.jpg','.png','.bmp']]
```